# Synchronize an async Task in WinForms-Validating-Event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await

I have a classic WinForms app which communicates async with the server api. That is realized by async await pattern.

Now I have a problem with the 'Validating'-Event. We use this event for client-side Validation (check if input is null) and set cancel.
If input is valid then I send the input to server async and await the result.

There is my problem. Now the control means that it is valid. When the callback set the cancel event to false it is too late.

Here ist my code:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    private async void Button1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CustomerName == null)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var isValidAndSaved = await SaveOnServerAsync(CustomerName);

            // Here is the Problem: Setting e.Cancel in callback is too late.
            if (isValidAndSaved)
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <returns>True if the given model was valid and save operation was successfull.</returns>
    public async Task<bool> SaveOnServerAsync(string customerName)
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000); // Send given customerName to server in real app.
        return customerName.Contains("%") ? false : true;
    }
}
```

I tried classic programming (synchron) for this case by 'Wait' the taks in main thread. But then I generated a deadlock.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; } = "3";

    private void Button1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CustomerName == null)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Deadlock because MainThread waits for callback. 
            var isValidAndSaved = SaveOnServerAsync(CustomerName).Result;
            if (isValidAndSaved)
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <returns>True if the given model was valid and save operation was successfull.</returns>
    public async Task<bool> SaveOnServerAsync(string customerName)
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000); // Send given customerName to server in real app.
        return customerName.Contains("%") ? false : true;
    }
}
```

Has anyone an idea for a good pattern?

If I set Cancel to false before await the async task then my problem would be that the user click is discarded and the user experience is sufficient.

Comment: Sadly you are going to have to make it synchronous

Comment: Have you an idea how to make it synchronous? If I try it then my GUI thread is frozen (see the second code-example).

Comment: Does it deadlock or just blocks? Anyway, the `Validate` event is a UI validation event. Your first check (`CustomerName`) is a valid check. The other call should be a `Click` event.

Comment: In our app the save command is invoked without a button. Save occurrs when the form looses focus. The goal is that the user is captured in the form as long it is unsaved or aborted. The form is not on a separate window but on a docking element with other forms and grids.

Comment: IMHO you are misusing the `Validating` event. It is intended for validating, not for committing changes.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You are right, I think so too. But our existing software is build in a way which requires that. We using the GridControl from DevXpress and allow the user creating and editing in a grid row. If the user want to leave the row then it is only allowed if input was valid and saved successfully. If saving failed the user should be captured in the row as long he press ESC.

Comment: I have worked with DevXpress in the past, but I have forgot the details. There are lots of events in this library. I would bet that there is an event specifically intended for saving the changes, and this event should not be the `Validating`. They have also great customer support, that you could take advantage of.

Comment: Yes. The official EventHandler for saving a Row would be 'RowUpdated'. But in my environment that event should not be used. We have a Web-Api which validates for the client. So validation occurs async. That's a crazy, modern like, architekture for plattform plattform like WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working way. Except the first Task all other tasks need "**ConfigureAwait(false)**".
See method '**SaveOnServerAsync**'.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; } = "3";

        private void Button1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CustomerName == null)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                var isValidAndSaved = SaveOnServerAsync(CustomerName).Result;
                if (isValidAndSaved)
                {
                    e.Cancel = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <returns>True if the given model was valid and save operation was successfull.</returns>
        public async Task<bool> SaveOnServerAsync(string customerName)
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000)
                // The solution is that all deeper Tasks need line below.
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            ;
            return customerName.Contains("%") ? false : true;
        }
    }
```

I found many articles about that problem. It sounds a bit of missconcept from MS.

---

Figure 3 of this MS article explains the deadlock situation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

The solution to avoid deadlocks is explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#configure-context

Comment: "It sounds a bit of missconcept from MS" - they didn't have `async`/`await` when they designed Windows Forms. Forward compatibility is hard.

Comment: I didn't mean the validation-event. I mean the ConfigureAwait(false) is a missconcept. Every method in my bib needs that overhead. Only a small subset in ViewModel-Commands wants the GUI-Sync-Context.